# How do I rotate the highlighted faces in the photo below without the previous face showing as well?

Tags: edit-mode, faces, customization

I have applied all transformations before I used the inset tool, now I am trying to rotate the highlighted faces to straighten them, but each time I try it leaves extra lines(where the face was before rotation, see second picture)

[image: Picture #1- before faces are rotated]
[image: picture #2- after I rotate the face]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to BSE,

It looks like you may have some duplicate vertices.

Please try the following steps **before** try to rotate your object:

- Select your object and press Tab to enter Edit Mode
- Press A to select all vertices
- Press M > Merge by Distance

This will merge any vertices that are sharing the same space ("sitting on top of each other"), and I believe should resolve the problem you are having.